# JQUERY Tablesorter not sorting numeric columns correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm having problems sorting columns that contain floating point numbers and integers:

**Example**

Column currently being sorted like so :

```
4697.2
403.95
399.38
317.94
316.44
3138.7
308.28
262.75
1839.5
179.94
159.97
145.99
103.95
94.95
90.24
819.9
```

I would like to sort the column by value as it appears to be sorting the figures by character length at the moment - possibly?

Here's my javascript :

```
<script>

$(function(){
    $('table').tablesorter({
        widgets        : ['zebra', 'columns', 'stickyHeaders'],
        usNumberFormat : false,
        numberSorter: function (a, b, direction) {
    if (a >= 0 && b >= 0) { return direction ? a - b : b - a; }
    if (a >= 0) { return -1; }
    if (b >= 0) { return 1; }
    return direction ? b - a : a - b;
}
    });
});

</script>
```

Could somebody please let me know what I need to do to correct this? 
Thanks

Comment: just a guess, but you set usNumberFormat false, the sorter should then expect numeric values like 430,95... either change your values or use true

Comment: Why do you need the extra code in the `numberSorter`? It should work properly without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was suggested by @fuchs777. The usNumberFormat setting was set to false. Which meant the tablesorter was treating the values as if they were in German number format, e.g. `1.234.567,89`. With German number format the thousands are denoted by periods (full stops) and not commas.

The fix was setting `usNumberFormat : true`

For example:

```
$(function(){
    $('table').tablesorter({
        widgets        : ['zebra', 'columns', 'stickyHeaders'],
        usNumberFormat : true,
        numberSorter: function (a, b, direction) {
        if (a >= 0 && b >= 0) { return direction ? a - b : b - a; }
        if (a >= 0) { return -1; }
        if (b >= 0) { return 1; }
        return direction ? b - a : a - b;
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Nothing has changed. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @fuchs777 suggested the answer: `usNumberFormat : true`.

Comment: @fuchs777 Yes it would. When usNumberFormat was set to false - it was assuming the values were German number format. In German number format thousands are denoted by periods and not commas.

Comment: @Donal after years of using js I still don't trust that automatic type casting ;)

Answer (score 2):

you set usNumberFormat false, the sorter should then expect numeric values like 430,95... either change your values to use "," as decimal separator or use

```
usNumberFormat : true
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you convert the values a and b to floats with parseFloat before doing any calculation or comparison?

```
a = parseFloat(a);
b = parseFloat(b);
```